# Piping ls to grep. Why does grep disregard the output from the ls command?

Tags: bash, command-line, grep, regular-expression, ls

I am trying to use this command `ls -p | egrep "\<[A-Z]+\>"` to print all uppercase file and dir names with dir names having / appended. I do not understand why my command works even though I said to grep only file/dir names with all upper case letters. I get the correct output but don't understand how a dir like XXX/ is also listed by grep.

Comment: By default, `grep` outputs lines that *contain* the pattern. To output only whole-line matches, you would need to add `-x`, or anchor the pattern with `^` and `$`.

Comment: In what way does grep "disregard the output"?  How does what it produces differ from what you expect it to produce?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you question is "why does `DIRNAME/` match the extended regular expression `\<[A-Z]+\>`, even though it has a character in it that is not an uppercase letter (`/`)?".

Your regular expression matches anything that contains a *word* that is all uppercased:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "this is not matched" "this IS matched" | egrep "\<[A-Z]+\>"
this IS matched
```

The `\<` and `\>` matches a zero-width "word boundary", i.e. the space between a "word character" and a character that is not of that type (or the start/end of the line).  A word character is any character in the class `[[:alpha:]_]` (letters and underscore).

Your expression matches something like `DIRNAME/` since `DIRNAME` matches the expression (there's a word boundary before the `D` and after the `E`).

---

To filter out specific names from a directory listing, don't use `grep` or other line-based text manipulation tools.  Filenames can contain newlines, so line-based tools would have a hard time doing the right thing unless you impose restrictions on filenames.

Instead, to get all uppercase names in a directory in `bash`:

```
$ ls -p -d *
DIR/     FILE     TEST123  dir/     file     test123
```

```
$ ls -p -d !(*[[:lower:]]*)
DIR/     FILE     TEST123
```

This requires `shopt -s extglob` to enable extended globbing patterns.  The extended globbing pattern `!(*[[:lower:]]*)` matches anything that does not contain any lowercase letters.

Note that the pattern does not care about the `/` that `ls -p` adds to directory names.  This is because the pattern matches filenames, and there is no filename containing the character `/`.  Also, the pattern is expanded *before* `ls` is invoked.

If you additionally want to weed out names containing digits, use

```
$ ls -p -d !(*[[:lower:][:digit:]]*)
DIR/  FILE
```

(this excludes any name that contains at least one lowercase letter or digit)
or,

```
$ ls -p -d !(*[[:lower:]]*|*[[:digit:]]*)
DIR/  FILE
```

(this excludes any name that contains at least one lowercase letter, and also excludes any name that contains at least one digit).

Answer (score 0):

```
$  ls -p | egrep "[A-Z]+"
ABC
$  ls -p ???             
ABC  fif  out
```

For me it was the word-boundary matching that changed the behaviour.

`ls -p | egrep "\<[A-Z]+\>"` gives no output in my case.

Compare `ls -f |cat` and `ls -p |cat`. When you start tweaking your regex you will find out: one shouldn't bother with *these things*: too complicated, and in the end it is not advised to **parse** ls systematically: ls output is only a "report", not a list of files to work with i.e. to do operations on. (Like a *screenshot* of a "explorer" window in MS Windows, almost.)

```
$  ls -p |cat 
ABC
XYZ/

$  ls -f |cat 
XYZ
ABC
```

Even the ordering is different; that slash `/` should not be used to filter directories.

It takes something like `find . -type d` (lists only directories, in all subdirs also) and then you have a good starting point for any filesystem search.

```
$  find . -type d 
.
./XYZ
./d3
./d3/d2
./d3/d1
./d2
./d1
```

Your specifation is right between a simple ls (maybe with a grep trick) and some clean solution with `find`. I don't give one - all depends on your temperament and your future plans regarding listing of "raw" filesystem info.

This illustrates the difference:

```
 $  find . -name "d1"
./d3/d1
./d1

$  ls -R |grep d1
d1
./d1:
d1
./d3/d1:
```

With ls-grep you get "additional" lines and characters. In a desperate situation, in the shell interactively: why not? (you know that file "d1" is *somewhere*)

But anything scripted should rely on `find` and it's many possibilities. It turns your filesystem into a database: query and report: two steps. `ls` is only the quick all-in-one tool on the command line.

### `$ ls -p -d !(*[[:lower:]]*|*[[:digit:]]*)`

Is this really serious? What about some strategical advice, instead of this? See comments etc.

O maybe you want to be around for every one liner any user ever could come up with. So *baroque*. Me I do *roots* style.

---

Comment: what system are you running where `egrep "\<[A-Z]+\>"` doesn't work? The word-break matches aren't standard, so it's possible they don't work everywhere, but they do seem to be well-supported in Linux (and FreeBSD, if I understand correctly)

Comment: @ilkkachu I have "normal" arch. My /usr/bin/egrep is just `exec grep -E ...`, and that is GNU grep 3.3. `ls -p | cat -A` shows all the colors (as line noise) of course. I just copy pasted. This file-and-dir-with-slash thing is a non-problem. `dmesg -L=always |less -R` or `ls -R |less -R` I find more interesting. (regex is a "separate" thing, only quite connected to `ls` -- mantra is dont parse (OK but what else?))

Comment: right, it's the colors that break it for you. Try it with `ls --color=auto | grep ...`. if you have `ls` aliased to `ls --color`.

Comment: @ilkkachu Either you are a very clever bot or a not so clever _teacher_. I am neither bot, nor "not so clever", nor a teacher. Why on earth should I try this? What about my answer? Too long? Not answering the Q? I have to read a link first?

Comment: I didn't say you're a bot, I only suggested that the coloring might be the difference between your case and that of the OP. That is, in case you care and didn't already find out a reason for that. If you don't care, or you already knew it, then nevermind.

Comment: @ilkkachu My statement is the Q is a textbook example of **"Why you should not parse ls output"**. Example Nr.2 that is. Nr. 1 is whitespace etc.. You guys avoid META layer first of all. I feel very very alone here. And manipulated. But hush.

Comment: what's the META layer here? Yes, the possibility of `ls` outputting colors is one reason it's not such a good idea to parse it with `grep`. But it _works for them_, well enough anyway, and the thing they're primarily asking doesn't seem to really be about that, but about why the `grep` matches what it does. I don't see that actually addressed in your post.

Comment: I will after all read the SE U&L after all. I only read "Community"'s profile. Very interesting, but also left quite open. If you are not a bot then you must have some interest here. My interest is pleasure, I am an amateur. Not a posix certified "teacher" trying to get sth running.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `\>` means *match at end of word*. What you want is probably

```
ls | egrep "^[A-Z.]+$"
```

where `^` matches at the beginning of the line and and `$` matches at the end of the line.